# My EBS health status is degraded as a result of initial wrong configuration

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i initially tried to deploy my Django app with EBS several times and it failed. I then investigated and discovered from the logs that the django.config file in my .ebextensions had the wrong settings instead of
‘‘‘option_settings:
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
WSGIPath: myapp.wsgi:application
‘‘‘

I used the one on the documentation which was
‘‘‘option_settings:
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application
‘‘‘
Now whenever I try to redeploy again after making this change I still get the 502 Bad Gateway on the browser and in the logs it still says this

‘‘‘ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebdjango'. ‘‘‘
I deleted my .elasticbeanstalk file and tried to create another application with a different name which shows up in the config.yml in the .elasticbeanstalk, but I still get the 502 error and the logs showing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebdjango'